# Set more than one path to an sObject

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have a custom object and 2 picklist fields.

I want to add a path to both of those fields and display more than one path in my page layout.

Once I have added one path and assigned it to a field in my `Grant Report` custom object:

[image]

I cannot add a new path to this same custom object:

[image]

(I cannot find the `Grant Report` custom object in the object list anymore)

**QUESTION**

Is there a limitation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign different path to different record types. So here you need to create multiple record types.

You can't assign multiple path based on fields.

From Trailhead:

> If you set up record types, you can have one path for each record
>   type. For example, in the record type New Business, include more
>   prospecting-related fields, but in the record type Existing Customer,
>   include a field or stage for renewals.

[Explore the New Sales Tools](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_whatsnew/units/lex_migration_whatsnew_crm)

Comment: all these are the same record types - Yes I need to assign multiple path based on fields, are you sure it is not possible? I cannot find any documented limitation

Comment: @ItaiShmida for now I'm sure. I will try to find one for you.

Comment: @ItaiShmida answer updated with reference.

Comment: real answer here - as of today it in not possible, so I vote on this answer